# Twitter Bootstrap - Row Div and Span Divs 1px Size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently creating a Landing page in Twitter Bootstrap and have run into a problem.  The row and that spans contained within that row are you being filled by the content.  They are each coming across as 1px in height.

http://www.landing.xeonweb.com.au - Is the URL

Below is the code:

```
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">




<!--Bootstrap Js-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="headerwrapper">
<div id="header" class="container">

   <div class="row">

     <div class="span5">
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Barrier Reef Pools Newcastle">
                </div>

                <div id="contactbutton">
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" type="button">Contact Us</button>
                </div>

     </div>


   <div class="span5">


   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item"><img src="img/majestichead.jpg" alt="Majestic Range" /></div>
    <div class="active item"><img src="img/barrierhead.jpg" alt="Barrier Reef Range" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/indulgencehead.jpg" alt="Indulgence Range" /></div>

  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

   </div>       

    <!--end Row-->  
        </div>      

<!--end Header-->       
  </div>            
<!-end Head wrap-->
</div>
```

The header is not responsive eiether which I am thinking is because of this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div class="row-fluid">`
instead of `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 0):

Well you have messed up the whole bootstrap code , the best practice is to write custom styling in a different css file than to include them into the bootstrap main css .

Try this --

Plz use the default styling -

```
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrapcombined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
   <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
  <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a></p>
</div>
     <div class="span6">
     <!--  Carousel code here-->



     <!-- end carousel -->
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```